# Any tutorials on how to make a leaderboard and achievements in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

I have tried google it but I can't find one that looks legit. I have game center all set up just need to get the leaderboard up and achievements up. Any suggestions would be nice. Thank you. Also, since I have my score saved to a string do I some how put that in leaderboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add leader board delegates to your layer class.

```
@interface MyMainMenu : CCLayer<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>
```

Display leader board on your need basis.

```
-(void)displayLeaderboard
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardViewController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    leaderboardViewController.leaderboardDelegate = self;

    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [app.navController presentModalViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Add these two leader board delegates function

```
#pragma mark GameKit delegate

-(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To submit score:

```
[[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterObject] reportScore:score forCategory: kLeaderboardID];
```

Use GameCenterManager.m class from GKTapper sample (see your apple sdk sample).

Here is code to get value from preference:
// To get saved value from  pref

```
int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole chapter on game center programming, with sample code, in Itterheim & Loew's book "Learn Cocos2d Game Development with iOS5". Also "Learning Cocos2d" by Strougo & Wenderlich has a chapter with working code.